# How to run modelica model using OMPython with external library package (i.e. Buildings)

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica

I am struggling to load my model with external library. **RoomM** is my model and **Buildings** is my library package exported externally to Modelica. Below is the code:

```py
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ

from OMPython import ModelicaSystem

omc = OMCSessionZMQ()

omc.sendExpression("loadModel(Modelica)")

omc.sendExpression("loadModel(C:\OpenModelica1.18.1-64bit\lib\omlibrary\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings\Buildings.mo)")

model_path=omc.sendExpression("loadFile(\"C:\Modelica-python\Modelica-Model/RoomM.mo\")")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [loadModel](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#loadmodel) to load Modelica libraries that are located in a location OpenModelica knows about (OpenModelica installation directory, `%HOME%/.openmodelica/libraries` and locations from environment variable `OPENMODELICALIBRARY`).

If you installed Buildings library with the package manager you can use

```py
import OMPython
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ

omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
omc.sendExpression("loadModel(Buildings, {\"9.1.0\"})")
```

`False` is returned in case `omc` can't find the specified library for the given version. You can use the [package manager](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/1.19/packagemanager.html) to install it.

---

If you want to load the `package.mo` file instead you need to use [loadFile](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#loadfile):

```
import OMPython
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ

omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
omc.sendExpression("loadFile(\"C:\OpenModelica1.18.1-64bit\lib\omlibrary\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings\Buildings.mo\")")
```

Remember to escape quoted strings with `\"` if the API function has string inputs.

See also the [OMPython section of OpenModelica User's Guide](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/ompython.html?highlight=loadmodel#test-commands). It has an example on how to load Modelica libraries and files.

Comment: omc.sendExpression("loadModel(Buildings, {\"9.1.0\"})")
   ...False
 omc.sendExpression("simulate(RoomM, stopTime=3.0)")
   ...{'resultFile': '',
   'simulationOptions': "startTime = 0.0, stopTime = 3.0, numberOfIntervals = 
   500, 
   tolerance = 1e-06, method = 'dassl', fileNamePrefix = 'RoomM', options = '', 
   outputFormat = 'mat', variableFilter = '.*', cflags = '', simflags = ''",
   'messages': 'Failed to build model: RoomM',

Comment: @ AnHeuermann thanks for the reply. The above is the code and still "simulate" syntax gives error that "Failed to build model"

Comment: omc is failing to load `Buildings` (it returns `False`). Try installing the library with the package manager. If that doesn't help load the package.mo with `loadFile`.

Comment: @sophie Did it work for you? If so you can accept this answer. Otherwise you might want to update your question with what you tried to do to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks AnHeuermann. It worked and I accepted the answer.

Comment: However running the code on ........mod=ModelicaSystem("RoomM.mo","RoomM",["C:\OpenModelica1.18.1-64bit\lib\omlibrary\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings\package.mo"])     doesn't load Buildings library again